# Фигуры в css на различных экранах

Tags: html, css

Добрый день всем. Вопрос: как при помощи css круг сделать под любой экран? width, height и border-radius в процентах дают круг на одних экранах и эллипс на других.

Comment: Для диспропорциональных экранов у вас ничего не получится) Софт не в курсе, что там жесть неоткалиброванная.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ширину с высотой нужно делать одинаковыми, тогда всё должно быть норм.

```css
circle {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.half_w {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
}

.tenth_h {
  width: 10vh;
  height: 10vh;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<circle class="tenth_h red"></circle>
<circle class="half_w red"></circle>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, помогло)

Answer (score 0):

Через псевдоэлемент-распорку с `padding-top: 100%`.

```css
.circle {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.circle:before {
  content:'';
  padding-top: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class=circle></div>
```

Comment: Этот вариант тоже опробую) Спасибо